# react-navigation navigation hook type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using this hook from react-navigation and instead of calling the hook again in different components, I want to pass `navigation` as a prop.

```
const navigation = useNavigation();
...
  <MyButton
     resetLocation={resetLocation}
     navigation={navigation}
  />
```

But I am unable to figure out the "type" for this navigation prop that I should pass into my MyButton component.

```
type MyButtonProps = {
  resetLocation: (locationToReset: string) => void;
  navigation: any;
};

export const MyButton: React.FunctionComponent<MyButtonProps> = ({
  resetLocation,
  navigation,
```

What should I replace `navigation: any;` with?

Comment: isnt it of type NavigationScreenProp<NavigationState, NavigationParams>

Comment: @SaachiTech I am able to import NavigationState from '@react-navigation/native' but not the other two. How could I get those?

Comment: Sorry, its NavigationProp<ParamListBase> here is the link https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/useNavigation.tsx

Comment: Yup that works. Do you want to write as an answer? @SaachiTech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NavigationProp<ParamListBase>`

Here is the definition of useNavigation, I pasted it here just in case.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import type { ParamListBase } from '@react-navigation/routers';
import NavigationContext from './NavigationContext';
import type { NavigationProp } from './types';

/**
 * Hook to access the navigation prop of the parent screen anywhere.
 *
 * @returns Navigation prop of the parent screen.
 */
export default function useNavigation<
  T extends NavigationProp<ParamListBase>
>(): T {
  const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);

  if (navigation === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "Couldn't find a navigation object. Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?"
    );
  }

  return navigation as T;
}
```

Here is the link for more info https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/main/packages/core/src/useNavigation.tsx